# Driver for Intel centrino n-2230 with FRU 04w3765

Tags: drivers, 14.04, intel-wireless

I got fed up with my Lenovo e530's BCM43228 that didn't start working so I bought a special Intel centrino n-2230 04w3765 because of Lenovo whitelisting the wifi cards on BIOS. Now I faced a smaller problem that still seems to be too much for me. Now that the PCIe card has a different ID(if i understood the idea) the system can't find the right driver for it. So how can i force my system to use the right driver for Intel centrino n-2230? If you need some information, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Intel uses the driver *iwlwifi* that is present in all recent Ubuntu versions. I will be very surprised if it is not loading already. Check:

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

If it is not loaded, load it:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If it is loaded already, check the message logs for errors or other clues:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Be sure the switch is set to enable wireless:

```
rfkill list all
```

Finally, it will be helpful to know your Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Sometimes, there is a laptop mode driver that is supposed to translate key presses, Fn+F2 for example, into action. Sometimes it doesn't work correctly. Please show us:

```
rfkill list all
```

Also check to see if the wireless is disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks @chili555 for the quick answer. I have the iwlwifi and it has detected the chip according to `dmesg | grep iwl` But rfkill says Wireless LAN is hard blocked. It has been since the problems begun with the broadcom chip a long time ago but it wasn't when I first (and again) installed Ubuntu. Now using 14.04LTS.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: It was disabled in BIOS which took me the long way. But now I scored the goal! Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I am not reputable enough to send you a comment, but I just wanted to wish you luck with the centrino n-2230.  I have seen many reports of issues, as well as first hand experience with 350 laptops riddled with issues on a school network.  This particular card is troublesome, especially with Cisco home products and Unifi access points if you are dealing with those.  I purchased Realtek rtl8 188ce FRU 60y3249 cards to replace them. They work fine in lenovo e430c laptops and don't have the same issues.

There was a recent post about externally installing drivers.  This may help you out:

[Externally Install Ubuntu Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454761/externally-install-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

After realising that the chip being hard blocked was the problem I decided to go to my BIOS  and ended up reseting defaults on it and adding the UEFI entry from a live USB session with Boot-Repair to get back to my OS. Now the wifi works. But I can't say that I would suggest anybody to do the same.