# Externally Install Ubuntu Drivers?

Tags: wireless, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm going to be installing Ubuntu 14.04 within the next few hours, and I've noticed that every time I install Ubuntu on my laptop, I never have any networking or graphics drivers. I always have to connect to Ethernet and install them, and it's really a pain as this laptop has a broken screen and keyboard, and it's mouse is barely working. I have it hooked up to a monitor, USB keyboard, and mouse.

So, basically my question is, can I download drivers for my graphics and network adapter before going into Ubuntu, and put them on my external hard drive to install when I get settled into Ubuntu and everything. Is this possible or should I prepare to have to run Ethernet cables all through my house?

Edit:
My machine has a Broadcom wireless card, I think. I've always installed Broadcom drivers every time I install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to include packages in an Ubuntu distribution by using [UCK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/).

> Ubuntu Customization Kit is a tool that helps you customizing official Ubuntu Live CDs (including Kubuntu/Xubuntu and Edubuntu) to your needs. You can add any package to the live system, for example language packs, or applications.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install uck
```

Here is a guide if you want to do it manually without UCK

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Also, can you access the terminal in Installation? I never knew that. How do you do it?